# Why am I getting mv errors with this sed command?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Given the following directory:

```
[~/test]find .
.
./something_else.txt
./univision.rbw
./something_else.rb
./testtest
./testtest/weewee.rb
./testtest/weewee.txt
./univision.rb
```

Running the following sed command generates a lot of `mv` errors:

```
[~/test]for i in $( find . ); do mv $i `echo $i | sed  s/test/this_is_not_a_test/g`; done; 
mv: ‘.’ and ‘./.’ are the same file
mv: ‘./something_else.txt’ and ‘./something_else.txt’ are the same file
mv: ‘./univision.rbw’ and ‘./univision.rbw’ are the same file
mv: ‘./something_else.rb’ and ‘./something_else.rb’ are the same file
mv: cannot stat ‘./testtest/weewee.rb’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘./testtest/weewee.txt’: No such file or directory
mv: ‘./univision.rb’ and ‘./univision.rb’ are the same file
```

but it also 'works'

```
[~/test]find .
.
./something_else.txt
./univision.rbw
./something_else.rb
./this_is_not_a_testthis_is_not_a_test
./this_is_not_a_testthis_is_not_a_test/weewee.rb
./this_is_not_a_testthis_is_not_a_test/weewee.txt
./univision.rb
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If the filename doesn't contain `test`, you are moving it over itself (as in `mv . ./.`). It emits the error, but doesn't change anything. Files with `test` in their names are renamed correctly.

Comment: right...of course.  so `mv -n $i  ...` should work

Comment: what mv -n does?

Comment: @FranciscoTapia: check `man mv`: -n, --no-clobber
              do not overwrite an existing file

Answer (score 0):

You first rename the directory `./testtest` to `./this_is_not_a_testthis_is_not_a_test`, and then further attepts to rename e.g. `./testtest/weewee.rb` will fail because that file is no longer there. You should use find's `-depth` option to process entries in the directory first, and the directory itself as the last step.